# PostgreSQL: Setted a full column to null value & database size increased. Why?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I´m working with PostgreSQL. I have a database named db_as on it with 25.000.000 rows of data. I wanted to set some diskspace free so I updated a full column to null value thinking that I would decrease databases size, but it didnt happend, in fact, i did the oposite thing, I increased databases size, and i dont know why. It increased from 700MB to 1425MB, thats a lot :( .

I used this sentence to know each columns size:

`SELECT sum(pg_column_size(_column)) as size FROM _table`

And this one to know all the databases size:

```
SELECT pg_database.datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)) AS size FROM pg_database;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original values will still be on disk, just dead.

Run a vacuum on the database to remove these.

```
vacuum full
```

Documentation 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: Thank you very much :)